# Is there anyway print a worksheet respecting the tabular data in it in python?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Let's say I created a workbook in python like this:

```
 import xlsxwriter
 workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(path)
 worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
```

Then populated and saved the worksheet.
In the future I will need to print the worksheet and ask the user to save the workbook. 
Is there anyway to print to the console this `worksheet` respecting the tabular data in it?

Comment: Print *to* the console, or print from the console to a printer?

Comment: To the console, I need to show the data to the user and ask to save.

Comment: I don't see any printing functions in the xlsxwriter documention, so you're probably going to have to write a function yourself that does the formatting.